# unable to install apache 2.2. Showing port 80 and 443 already in use

Tags: apache, xampp

unable to install apache 2.2.Showing port80 and 443 allreday in use.
Help needed

Asmita

Comment: Check your installed software and services to see what web servers you have installed. The ports are typical of regular and secure HTTP ports.

Answer (score 0):

You have a webserver running already. Assuming you're on some version of Linux (you don't say) you can identify the process running on that port using `lsof`.

```
lsof -i :80
```

See [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/184) for more detail